# how to replace , to . in large text file

Tags: perl

I wish to use perl and write a program that looks for latitude and longitude values in a large tab delimited text file (100000 rows), and replaces the , used in the lat long values to a . . the file has multiple columns.

ie. I want to change it to.

51,2356 to 51.2356

can someone show me how this is done?

many thanks,

Comment: I believe you should improve your question and add input and expected output if you would like to get more specific answer to your question. I also suggest showing some efforts what you have done so far yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a "program" for that, you do things like this with one liners really. If you want to replace **ALL** `,` (commas) in file with `.` (dots) in entire file (your question doesn't go into specifics of original file format) then below does the trick:

`perl -pi.bak -e 's/,/\./g;' your_file.txt`

It will also backup your file before running replace to `your_file.txt.bak`.

Comment: thanks for this, however, i would like the script to find the latitude and longitude values. ie. preceeds with one or two digits before the comma. how do you add this to hte search statement?

Answer (score 0):

**Quick and dirty way is to replace ALL commas by dots** ( if that will serve your requirement)

```
while (<$fh>) {
   $_ =~ s/,/\./g 
}
```

However, if there are other fields which might be affected, **better solution would be to replace only the desired columns**.

Assuming the two fields that you're interested are the first and second column of the tab-delimited file, ideally the two fields should be matched and then replaced with "dot".

```
while (<$fh>) {
    if ($_ =~ /(\d+,\d+)\|(\d+,\d+)\|(.*)$/) {
      my ($a, $b, $c) = ($1, $2, $3);
      $a=~s/,/\./g;
      $b=~s/,/\./g;
      $_= $a."|".$b."|".$c;
    }
}
```

Here, 
$a and $b will match the "latitude and longitude" columns.